# Parallel action is game

Tags: discussion

I been [suggested](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/249800/strategy-game-how-do-i-calculate-the-parallel-actions?noredirect=1#comment500289_249800) by [rwong](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/620/rwong), in programmers stack exchange, to ask for my [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/249800/strategy-game-how-do-i-calculate-the-parallel-actions) to be migrated at here.

Do you think I will find my answer at here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have them migrate the question here. You need to flag it on their site, as we don't have the power to take their questions, they need to give them to us.

Comment: Done, I asked them.